# convert and cast not working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am new to this. I am trying to change the column ID from float to varchar but get error message here. "The type name 'Programmer.dbo.'Diabetic Patient 12 years   ove$'' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 1.
" what is not correct here?

SELECT  *
      FROM [Programmer].[dbo].['Diabetic Patient 12 years   ove$']

```
  select convert ([Programmer].[dbo].['Diabetic Patient 12 years   ove$'].id as varchar(200))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try :

```
SELECT CAST(id AS varchar(200))
FROM [Programmer].[dbo].[Diabetic Patient 12 years ove$]
```

OR (to force integer format)

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(id AS BIGINT) AS varchar(200))
FROM [Programmer].[dbo].[Diabetic Patient 12 years ove$]
```

Comment: You will need to use CAST in that example

Comment: this gives error: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "Programmer.dbo.Diabetic Patient 12 years   ove$.id" could not be bound.

Comment: You have misspelled something... Try to find the right name for your table

Comment: this worked  SELECT CAST(id AS varchar(200))
    FROM [Programmer].[dbo].['Diabetic Patient 12 years   ove$']

Comment: but maybe I dont understand, it still shows the type as a float when I click on the columns

Comment: it's fine though I can use in crystal reports as a program query. Thank you for your help, God Bless you !

Comment: A add a forcing method to get an interger formating... Maybe it will helps you

Answer (score 0):

Convert works like the below example:

```
 Convert(VarChar(200), NAME_OF_COLUMN HERE )
```

Cast Will work like this:

```
Cast(NAME_OF_COLUMN HERE As VarChar(200))
```

I don't think there are any performance differences between them,

Comment: I tried this SELECT  *
  FROM [Programmer].[dbo].['Diabetic Patient 12 years   ove$']
  
   Convert(VarChar(200),[Programmer].[dbo].['Diabetic Patient 12 years   ove$'].[ID])

Comment: it has this error Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Convert'.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this:

```
Select STR(tbl.id) FROM [Programmer].[dbo].[*tablename*] tbl
```

Comment: Clive, I have this:   Select CONVERT(ID AS varchar(200)) FROM [Programmer].[dbo].['Diabetic Patient 12 years   ove$']

Comment: What is the name of the table? And is that the whole SQL code that you are running?

Comment: but error:Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.  yes that is all i ran your statement

Comment: Can you try this:  Select STR(id) FROM [Programmer].[dbo].['Diabetic Patient 12 years ove$']

Comment: it gives this error: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'Programmer.dbo.'Diabetic Patient 12 years ove$''.

Comment: maybe because i am using sql express? sql express sql server 9.0.500

Comment: Are you sure that 'Programmer.dbo.'Diabetic Patient 12 years ove$' is the table name? As I'm finding that a bit strange. Is it possible to print screen the tables. No Sql Express shouldn't be the problem

Comment: yes i am able to do a simple select  on that exact.

Comment: Is this the select select statement that you are writing: SELECT * FROM [Programmer].[dbo].['Diabetic Patient 12 years ove$']

Comment: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid object name 'Programmer.dbo.'Diabetic Patient 12 years ove$''. this way does not work. i copied the name when i did the right click select top 1000

Comment: Does this work? -> SELECT Id FROM [Programmer].[dbo].['Diabetic Patient 12 years ove$']

Comment: no Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'Programmer.dbo.'Diabetic Patient 12 years ove$''.

Comment: And what about this? -> SELECT [Programmer].[dbo].['Diabetic Patient 12 years ove$'].id <- if this works, you can try: SELECT STR([Programmer].[dbo].['Diabetic Patient 12 years ove$'].id)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(200), id) FROM [Programmer].[dbo].[your_table]
```

You simply have a type-o.  If you get errors like that it's a good idea to just read through an example of what command you are trying to do, CONVERT in this case.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql  And then just chuck your own columns and tables in.